# Send RAWs from Sony RX100 to Android smartphone

Tags: sony

First, some context so maybe someone will have a good suggestion: I'm currently touring with my bike. My Android smartphone is basically my computer, and it's ok (considering the weight saved, it's even more than ok). I use Snapseed on my phone to do basic treatment on the photos I take (mostly light & dark and colors).

I shoot in RAWs zith a Sony RX100 mk 3. For now, the only way for me to get the RAWs on my smartphone is to switch the SD card, which is a pain. I only need to transfer a few photos at a time. Sony's official app (Play Memories) only sends jpegs.

Is there a way to send RAWs by WiFi?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an [Eye-Fi](http://www.eyefi.com/) card could be a solution to your problem?

> BEyefi Mobi Pro is an SDHC memory card with a pro punch: available in 16GB and 32GB capacity, it includes built-in WiFi that connects your camera, at lightning speeds to your smartphone, tablet, PC or Mac. Just pop it into your camera and install any of our desktop or mobile apps to instantly transfer RAW and JPEG. Selective transfer gives you the freedom to choose which images transfer to your device. Mobi Pro will transfer images over your existing home network — or if you're on location, it will create and use a private, secure connection, for ultimate on-the-go convenience. For additional information see the tech specs.

Comment: That could have been an idea, but I'm currently in the middle of Patagonia, so I fear it's too ate to get that.